# Type signature of functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have defined three functions in haskell which multiply two numbers

```
k = \x y -> x * y

foo y = \x -> x * y

bar x = \x -> x * x
```

But I am getting different signatures for all the three functions.

```
λ> :t k
k :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
λ> :t foo
foo :: Num a => a -> a -> a
λ> :t bar
bar :: Num a => t -> a -> a
```

Can somebody explain why it is so? I can see t in type signature of bar. is it different from normal usage of a, b, or a1, a2 etc

Answer (score 6):

First of: all the signatures basically come from `(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` and your usage of it. And yes `k` and `foo` should be the same but `bar` is indeed a bit different as you wrote it here.

- `foo` should be obvious (I hope) (it's just that `*` is polymorphic and the type says just that)
- for `bar` it's because the `x` on the left side is not used on the `right` side so you get the extra parameter `t` - it's the same as `bar y = \x -> x * x`
- for `k` see the [Monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) - basically Haskell will pull a default-type here to work around some slight problems that could arise. It's a bit strange that you get it here because by default newer GHCi version should not show this behavior (see the link)

---

btw: don't wonder to much about the names of the types ;)

The lesson learned should probably be to just write down your signatures (at least on top-level functions) ^^ - it would have solved all your problems